# Проблема с Zlib inflate на python (есть рабочий код на c++)

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib

Всем привет. Я разрабатываю пакетного бота на онлайн игру. В игре используется tcp протокол с xor шифрованием и запаковкой методом Zlib deflate. Первый пакет от сервера начинается вот так: "78 9C 0A 9D 1F B5 37 EE 11 73 50 B3 C9 1A 25 00 00 00 00 FF FF 32 6E 8B DA 2B 9A 73 24 E4 FF FF FD 52 66 4C 47 BC 5E 24 7D 7F FD 67 D5 75 00 00 00 00 FF FF".
У меня уже есть рабочий алгоритм на C++, но мне понадобилось портировать код на python чтобы установить бота на веб сайт. Я перепробовал все примеры с первых трех страниц поисковика google, но мне во всех выдавало ошибку -3 с разным содержанием.
Аргументы для deflate с сервера игры выглядят так:

```
 cl->Zstrm.zalloc = zlib_alloc;
 cl->Zstrm.zfree = zlib_free;
 cl->Zstrm.opaque = NULL;
 int result = deflateInit( &cl->Zstrm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION );
 deflate( &cl->Zstrm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH )
```

Подскажите как сделать распаковку на Python, zlib.decompress и zlib.decompressobj выдают мне ошибку. В случае с примером результат распаковки должен выглядеть так: "55D19F5AD08567C2B6375372D093D08F
5FD0A0E280A05AD08509D0BE0408D18F
D18FD0BFE2809A3B02D094D0B33862D1
87D197D0ACD084D0A7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Первый пакет от сервера..."* - А остальные? ;)
Ну, ок, поработаем с тем, что есть...

```
import zlib
data = "789C0A9D1FB537EE117350B3C91A2500000000FFFF326E8BDA2B9A7324E4FFFFFD52664C47BC5E247D7FFD67D57500000000FFFF"
res = zlib.decompress(bytes.fromhex(data))
```

Если пытаться распаковать, то претензий к формату нет, но ругается на то, что входные данные обрываются.

```
error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

---

Если распаковывать как stream, то ошибок нет (но всё равно, данные таки не все, статус показывает, что конец стрима не достигнут).

```
import zlib
data = "789C0A9D1FB537EE117350B3C91A2500000000FFFF326E8BDA2B9A7324E4FFFFFD52664C47BC5E247D7FFD67D57500000000FFFF"
z = zlib.decompressobj()
res = z.decompress(bytes.fromhex(data))
print(res.hex())
print(f"EOF={z.eof}  unused={len(z.unused_data)}  unconsumed={len(z.unconsumed_tail)}")
```

```
559f5abd5ee203528334ac2233865abd156cc454ffffbf1a3602c44ae862f7ebfcaad7
EOF=False  unused=0  unconsumed=0
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я на вход отправлял данные в виде текста cp1251 конвертированного в байты, возможно поэтому не работало